# Unable to perform Drag and Drop in Selenium Web-Driver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

Below is the code . Drag and Drop is not working. Please let me know what is wrong in my code.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String URL ="http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop";
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait  frame_Test = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    frame_Test.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("iframeResult")));
    WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='drag1']"));
    WebElement To =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='div1']"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.clickAndHold(From).moveToElement(To).release(From).build( ).perform();
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: No error message ... It runs and stops without dragging the element happens

Comment: Please take a look at this link which states that there is an issue with drag and drop in HTML5. It also suggests a workaround using **Javascript** and/or **jquery** : [https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6315](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6315)

Comment: Check the below video. It may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egdUfivmm-k

Answer (score 0):

what error are you getting? Have you tried below ?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source"));
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));    
(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

Comment: No error message ... It runs and stops without dragging the element happens

Comment: I tried it but still the same, Nothing happens. Cannot drag image into box.

Comment: check the element id or xpath used , they might not be correct.